# SQL Server Compact 4.0 connection string for Entity Framework code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, connection-string

I am creating an application for Windows XP so I am stuck with .Net framework 4.0. I tried to use SQL Server Compact and EF code first but it make an error when `update-database`.

I wish to put the database in my code directory to deploy in customer machine.

This is my connection string:

```
<add name="QuanLyKhoContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;AttachDBFileName=MyData.sdf" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And the error:

> This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.

Comment: Have a look at [ConnectionStrings.com for SQL Server Compact](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/) - your connection string is invalid, it should be something like `Data Source=MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;` (no `AttachDbFileName=` attribute or anything of that sort....)

Comment: What I don't understand is how you are using a SQL Server provider, but ask the question as SQL Server Compact.  These providers are not interoperable.

Answer (score 13):

In one of my projects I used SQL Server Compact 4.0 and my connection string was simple enough:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" 
            connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MyDB.sdf"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I think that **you should check your `providerName`**. I am not sure if `System.Data.SqlClient` is the right one.

Have you installed **[EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact/) NuGet package**? Once it is installed **`System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0` provider name** is added and it should be used in the connection string.

**Check if `SqlServerCompact` provider is added to your `web.config`.**

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Comment: I tried it but it's not working for mine, I don't know why it be:)

Comment: Painful, I can't install SqlserverCompact via nuget Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact (≥ 4.0.8854.1)'.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent this you need to change your connection string to have:

```
 Trusted_Connection=False;Persist Security Info=True
```

based on below link

http://jayhollingum.blogspot.in/2011/03/ef-codefirst-databasesetinitializser.html

Answer (score 1):

After many search, I decide to move to a near approach of SQL compact, it's LocalDB. I change it and this work:

```
<add name="QuanLyKhoContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|MyDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=60" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I think "System.Data.SqlClient" is a valid Provider because I am using Sql Express LocalDB :)
It's not my first purpose, but it work anyway. Thanks all

I just don't know when deploy in window XP, do I need to install Sql Express or Sql Compact stuffs manually?

Comment: Yes, at least `Sql Server Express` should be installed in order to use `LocalDB`. If `Sql Server Compact` is used then you do not need to instal additional soft. It is enough to have `Sql Server Compact` related `dll`s in you application folder.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#sqlce) you can use the following:

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
    connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFileName.sdf" />
```

PS: [How to install SQL Server Compact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_0)